# Why doesn't Cakephp Html::link() work as I expect it to?

Tags: cakephp

Using this code:

```
$sitemap = 4;

$link = $this->Html->link( $sitemap . '.xml', null, 
    array('plugin' => $this->request->plugin, 
        'controller' => $this->request->controller, 
        'action' => 'view', 
        'admin' => false));
```

I expect to get a link that looks like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/vreb_listings/vreb_listing_feeds/view/4.xml
```

Instead, I get this:

```
/admin/vreb_listings/vreb_listing_feeds/4.xml
```

What gives? The action => view is having no effect, as view doesn't show up in the url, and the admin => false isn't working either, as admin does show up. This code is in the admin area.

I haven't even looked up how to include the full domain path in the url. Also, I want the title text to be the same as the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3alink), the *second* parameter is the url one, so in your code it should be

```
$link = $this->Html->link( $sitemap . '.xml',  
                           array('plugin' => $this->request->plugin, 
                                 'controller' => $this->request->controller, 
                                 'action' => 'view', 
                                 'admin' => false));
```

(remove the null second parameter)

Oh, and for title text, *that* is the third parameter, so

```
$link = $this->Html->link( $sitemap . '.xml',  
                           array('plugin' => $this->request->plugin, 
                                 'controller' => $this->request->controller, 
                                 'action' => 'view', 
                                 'admin' => false),
                           array('title' => $sitemap.'.xml'));
```

should do the trick